# Laravel app deployment in Heroku fails with handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1

Tags: laravel, heroku

I am trying to deploy my laravel app to Heroku.

Deployment is failing while trying to run composer install.

It fails with the following error

```
    Package illuminate/html is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use laravelcollective/html instead.
       Generating optimized autoload files
       > Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
       > @php artisan package:discover --ansi

       In Facade.php line 236:

         A facade root has not been set.  


       Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1
 !     WARNING: A post-autoload-dump script terminated with an error
 !     ERROR: Dependency installation failed!
 !     
 !     The 'composer install' process failed with an error. The cause
 !     may be the download or installation of packages, or a pre- or
 !     post-install hook (e.g. a 'post-install-cmd' item in 'scripts')
 !     in your 'composer.json'.
```

Composer install works fine in my local system.

Seems to be then some problem with the environment in my local and heroku.

I have an APP_KEY defined in my Heroku env variable.

Best Regards,

Saurav

Comment: did you try delete vendor folder and try composer install again?

Comment: no...but ran composer update

Comment: i think some packages doesn't install correctly ,remove vendor folder and run composer install

Comment: in local or in the server container ? because in the local its working fine...i did the same in server but the same problem

Comment: root cause is same as marked in the original link...but i was getting it for using Log facade in my config files...i started using php native error_log and it started working...but i will check how to make the Log facade work in the config files